# Sending post inludes non-latin characters with python

Tags: python, wordpress

I have a WordPress website and I want to send some specific posts using python. When my posts includes no non-latin character, I have no problem, I can easily publish them.

However, when I use characters like *'ğ'* or *'ş'* in my post, it gives me a `parse error. not well formed` error. I have to use iso-8859-9 encoding due to language of my site and I couldn't solve this problem no matter what I've tried.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-9 -*-
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import posts
from wordpress_xmlrpc import WordPressPost


wp = Client('http://websiteurl/xmlrpc.php', 'username', 'pass')
#posts = wp.call(posts.GetPosts())
#print posts[0]

data="Güneş doğudan doğar"

post = WordPressPost()
post.title = 'My Post Title'
post.content = data
post.id = wp.call(posts.NewPost(post))

post.post_status = 'publish'
wp.call(posts.EditPost(post.id, post))
```

Comment: Try `post.content = data.decode("iso-8859-9")`

Comment: Please mark this question as resolved, if my answer solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I had no idea about marking process. Sorry about that. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is already encoded as `iso-8859-9`, so you'll want to `decode()` it in order to pass it through to WordPress. The problem line is `post.content = data`. You'll want to change it to:

```
post.content = data.decode("iso-8859-9")
```